# Call to undefined function datefmt_create() wamp

Tags: php, wamp, pecl

When using

```
echo datefmt_create("en_US" ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL,IntlDateFormatter::FULL);
```

I got a *call to undefined function* error.

It was working fine on another machine with the same PHP version, I also tried to print `phpinfo()` and it has no section of "intl"

Comment: Maybe a name space issue? Or maybe that extension has not been compiled in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding php to the path in system variable solved the issue

steps:
right click my computer -> advanced system settings -> then click environment variables button -> then in  system variables find the path item and add your php.exe parent folder to it in my case it was "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12"

Answer (score 1):

`IntlDateFomatter` is only available in PHP >= 5.3.0, PECL intl >= 1.0.0 so if you are running greater than PHP 5.3 then your problem is PECL intl is not installed.

[Read the Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php)

Comment: Yes, but you need PECL intl installed. It's usually bundled with 5.3 and higher, but it depends how PHP was installed for that machine.

Comment: the php was installed through wamp ... download wamp then installed it

Comment: how to check if the pecl included - compiled .... the pecl intl is checked in the extensions list

Comment: thanks for help... i solved the problem by adding php to the path variable