# Still get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function datefmt_create()" after different tries

Tags: php

With the following code

```
    $this->dataFormater = datefmt_create(
        "en_US",
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        "America/Edmonton",
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN
    );
```

I still get this error after tried the following:

1. According to [This solution from SO][1], php must be in the system path, so I verified that php is in the system path by running `php --version` from different directories.
2. Verified that PECL has been installed by running "pecl version" from command line. Tried that because of [this answer][2] and lots of similar ones from SO. The version command results in

   ```
   PEAR Version: 1.10.12
   PHP Version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.6
   Zend Engine Version: 4.1.2
   ```
3. **[EDIT]** Verified that I have `intl` extension installed already by `php -r '$all = get_loaded_extensions(); foreach($all as $i) { $ext = new ReflectionExtension($i); $ver = $ext->getVersion(); echo "$i - $ver" . PHP_EOL;}' |grep -i intl`.
   [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34527047/4381271
   [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34484847/4381271

Comment: You're checking the extension in command-line. Is the PHP code a command-line script too?

Answer (score 1):

You must have the `intl` extension installed to get access to that function.

The documentation for that is here https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error message although I can verifty I have the `intl` extension installed by `php -r '$all = get_loaded_extensions(); foreach($all as $i) { $ext = new ReflectionExtension($i); $ver = $ext->getVersion(); echo "$i - $ver" . PHP_EOL;}' |grep -i intl`. My `intl` version is `intl - 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.6`.

Comment: When calling php via the command line you are using php cli which typically uses a separat ini file than the php used by the webserver. This might be an apache module or php-fpm used by nginx. So you have to call those lines of php code from inside your browser if you want to figure out if you have intl installed correctly.